# Código deja de funcionar al ser creado como función

Tags: php

El siguiente código realiza una consulta a la DB y comprueba que el usuario existe, si se cumple obtiene su ID, email y contraseña.Funciona perfecto en php procedural.

```
$email = "uncorreo@gmail.com";
$password = "micontra";

$userDataQuery = "SELECT id, usuario_correo, usuario_pass FROM usuarios WHERE usuario_correo = ?";  
  if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $userDataQuery )) {         
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $email);       
    if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){                   
      mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);                
      if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) ==1){              
           mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $user_id, $user_email, $user_password);    
           mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);                   
          if("micontra" == $user_password){
            $error = "Oleeee";
            echo $error;
          } else {
            $error = "Contraseña incorrecta";
            echo $error;
          } 
      } else {
        $error = "Email no existe";
        echo $error;
      }
    } else {
      $error = "Error, intentelo otra vez";
      echo $error;
    }
  }
```

Sin embargo, al intentar crear una simple función a partir del mismo modificando los echo por returns, la función devuelve NULL.

```
function login() {
$email = "uncorreo@gmail.com";
$password = "micontra";

$userDataQuery = "SELECT id, usuario_correo, usuario_pass FROM usuarios WHERE usuario_correo = ?";  //Match query for users email address
  if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $userDataQuery )) {         //Prepares SQL statement
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $email);       //Binds variables to the prepared statement as parameters
    if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){                   //Executes a prepared query
      mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);                //Transfers a result set from a prepared statement
      if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) ==1){              //Return the number of rows in statements result set
           mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $user_id, $user_email, $user_password);    //Binds variables to a prepared statement for result storage
           mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);                   //Fetch results from a prepared statement into the bound variables
          if("micontra" == $user_password){
            $error = "Oleeee";
            return $error;
          } else {
            $error = "Contraseña incorrecta";
            return $error;
          }    
      } else {
        $error = "Email no existe";
        return $error;
      }
    } else {
      $error = "Error, intentelo otra vez";
      return $error;
    }
  }
}

echo login();
```

¿Por que  funciona el código correctamente fuera de una función y dentro no? ¿En principio solo tendría que cambiar los echo's por return's he hecho no?

Gracias de antemano por vuestra respuesta.

Comment: `$link` no está declarada dentro de la función. Deberías declararla o pasarla como parámetro.

Comment: Perfecto, era eso!
Lección aprendida: La funciones no tienen en cuenta las variables declaradas fuera.